# Is there a way to give my cookie pop up a delay of a few seconds?

Tags: jquery, cookies, popup, delay

I'm looking for a way to delay my pop-up with Jquery

Hi,

I'm notary good at Jquery so  I've been searching for a way to delay my pop up for a few seconds before it pops up. The Jquery for now is working with the cookies and all so that's great. But I can't figure out how to delay it for like 5 seconds before it pops up.

Can somebody help?

```
    jQuery('.close').click(function(){
      jQuery('#popup-container').fadeOut();
      jQuery('#active-popup').fadeOut();
  });



    var visits = jQuery.cookie('visits') || 0;


    visits++;

      jQuery.cookie('visits', visits, { expires: 1, path: '/' });

      console.debug(jQuery.cookie('visits'));

      if ( jQuery.cookie('visits') > 1 ) {
        jQuery('#active-popup').hide();
        jQuery('#popup-container').hide();
      } else {
          var pageHeight = jQuery(document).height();
          jQuery('#popup-container').show(0).delay(5000);
      }
```

It would  be great if someone could help me out with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the CSS to hide by default

```
#popup-container{
  display: none;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

and the javascript

```
if (jQuery.cookie('visits') > 1) {
  jQuery('#active-popup').hide();
  // jQuery('#popup-container').hide();
}
else {
  var pageHeight = jQuery(document).height();
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('#popup-container').show();
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: It does work, but when I go to a different page and go back to home the pop up comes back. but it only needs to show it once a session. Maybe a conflict of some sort?

Comment: I just took another look, but it just doesn't work, cookies work now but it still shows immediately even after replacing the code

Comment: can you create demo page?

Comment: I don't see the popup after navigating to  other page and back to home except it flashing when I hit back button. try edited answer.